# Get Xml version

Tags: php

I have a xml file and I want to get version and encoding number in PHP.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<from>John</from>
```

I want to get version and encoding information in PHP. (For this example 1.0 and ISO-8859-1)

How can I get it in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to do this.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('file.xml');
// or you can load the XML string
//$doc->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><from>John</from>');
$version = $doc->xmlVersion; // 1.0
$encoding = $doc->xmlEncoding; // ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket. Thats great. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use php's [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) interface:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('file.xml');
echo 'Version: ' . $doc->xmlVersion . "\n";   // Like '1.0', you can modify this
echo 'Encoding: ' . $doc->xmlEncoding . "\n"; // Like 'ISO-8859-1', readonly
```

These and other properties (such as `standalone`) of the document are documented in the documentation, ehm, [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.xmlencoding).

Comment: `$doc->version` should be `$doc->xmlVersion`.

Comment: @Tomalak , Rocket Oops, fixed.